# Create up-/down-slide or push effect with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am replacing the `src` of an image when the user has scrolled to a certain point of the page with this jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var sticky = jQuery(".sticky-icon-white");
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 115) {
            jQuery("#sticky-icon").attr("src", "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff");

        } else {
            jQuery("#sticky-icon").attr("src", "https://via.placeholder.com/100/");
            sticky.removeClass('not-sticky-icon-white').addClass('sticky-icon-white');
        }

        if (scroll >= 300) {
            sticky.removeClass('sticky-icon-white').addClass('not-sticky-icon-white');
        } else {
            sticky.removeClass('not-sticky-icon-white').addClass('sticky-icon-white');
        }
    });
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="sticky-icon-white">
   <img id="sticky-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/">
</div>
```

The replacing is working fine but I want to apply a slide or push (not sure what to call it) animation on it. Like this one: https://gosimple.com (the leaf icon in the middle).

But I couldn't figure out how. Could someone help me to find a solution, please?

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bzqad296/

Thanks in advance!

I have tried with `slideUp();` or `slideDown();` but it doesn't work.

EDIT:

In this image, you can see the effect. How the icon changes from white background, green leafs to green background, white leafs: 
https://prnt.sc/lgwr3f

Comment: Can you tell more about the effects you want? In which of that site are you referring to?

Comment: @SilentCoder, check out the edit in my question please. Thanks.